# RecordSortedList and temporary table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a performance issue with multiple temporary tables that I'm trying to solve with RecordSortedList, but I'm getting strange results. I have a temporary table that has a couple hundred thousand records being inserted into it, and then used elsewhere for joins to other temporary tables. The problem is after trace parsing this solution the insert is taking too long for all the individual inserts and I was hoping to use a RecordSortedList to bulk insert into the staging table. However, I can't find a handle to the temporary table after the RecordSortedList.insertDatabase() call.

I've tried something like this:

```
RecordSortedList tmpTableSortedList;
MyTempTable myTempTable;
AssetTrans assetTrans;
int i = 1;

tmpTableSortedList = new RecordSortedList(tableNum(MyTempTable));
tmpTableSortedList.sortOrder(fieldNum(MyTempTable, LineNum));

//the real scenario has a much more complicated data gathering, but just for sample
while select * from AssetTrans 
{
    myTempTable.AssetGroup = assetTrans.AssetGroup
    myTempTable.LineNum = i;

    tmpTableSortedList.ins(myTempTable);

    i++;

}

tmpTableSortedList.insertDatabase();

//strange things happen here
MyTempTable myTempTableCopy;
AnotherTmpTable anotherTmpTable;

tmpTableSortedList.first(myTempTableCopy); //returns a buffer, but not usable buffer in join.

//does not work, I imagine because the myTempTableCopy isn't actually pointing to the 
//inserted records above; somehow the temp table is out of scope.
while select * from anotherTmpTable
join myTempTableCopy
where anotherTmpTable.id == myTempTableCopy.id
{
    //logic
}
```

Is there a way to get a pointer to the temp table after the call to RecordSortedList.insertDatabase()? I've also tried linkPhysicalTable() and a few other things, but maybe RecordSortedList was not supposed to be used with tempDb tables?

Edit: Like Aliaksandr points out below this works with `RecordInsertList` instead of `RecordSortedList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but maybe RecordSortedList was not supposed to be used with tempDb tables?

Error message when using `TempDb` tables:

> `RecordInsertList or RecordSortedList operations are not allowed with database temporary tables.`

So it's not allowed, which might make sense because `RecordSortedList` is a memory-based object and `TempDb` tables are not. I would think you could though because I'm not sure there's a huge difference in a `TempDb` table and a `Regular` table when they're both stored on disk?

If you wanted to use an `InMemory` table, look at `\Classes\CustVendSettle` specifically the variable `rslTmpOverUnderReverseTax`, which uses an `InMemory` table.

**IF** `TempDb` tables were allowed, you would use `getPhysicalTableName()` to get the handle combined with `useExistingTempDBTable()`.

Or did I misread your question?

Comment: Can't use InMemory - need to be able to use joins later in the process and only tempdb allows that (or physical). Either way, looks like a re-design is inevitable, which is what I'm hoping to avoid due to the time it will take.

Comment: @rjv I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but your post makes it sound like iterative inserts is the problem, and if `RecordInsertList` speeds things up, do that `InMemory` then just dump the final table to a `TempDb`. At that point though, I'd think your performance issues are actually somewhere else. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

> does not work, I imagine because the myTempTableCopy isn't actually pointing to the inserted records above; somehow the temp table is out of scope.

Method `new` of `RecordSortedList` has additional `Common` parameter where you should pass your tempDB table buffer.

[image]

> Error message when using TempDb tables:

> RecordInsertList or RecordSortedList operations are not allowed with database temporary tables.

> So it's not allowed, which might make sense because RecordSortedList is a memory-based object and TempDb tables are not.

Although the message says we can't use temporary tables for such operations, indeed we can. We just need to be careful because the code must be executed on the server.

[RecordSortedList objects must be server-located before the insertDatabase method can be called. Otherwise, an exception is thrown.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa862829(v=ax.50))

> I have a temporary table that has a couple hundred thousand records being inserted into it

There is no limit to the size of a RecordSortedList object, but they are completely memory-based, so there are potential memory consumption problems. So this may not be the best solution in your case.

Comment: This doesn't work. After the call the insertDatabase() the tmp table object passed into the constructor is null. I've even tried to select the tmp table after the call just in case the cursor was at the end, but it is still null.

Comment: Have you tried it? The insert call just needs to be on the server in general. I believe the `TempDb` exclusion still applies. Please update your post with a code sample. I tested with `TmpNumberSeq`.

Comment: This works with `RecordInsertList` so I believe this should work with `RecordSortedList`, I will test and add the code when I get to the development environment.

Comment: It does in fact work with RecordInsertList. I'm not sure why RecordSortedList does not behave in the same manner. I will update the OP with this.